Add a secundary reverse x-axis ggplot2
I have the following data example of a spectral analysis.
    structure(list(x = c(0.555555555555556, 0.555555555555556, 0.555555555555556, 
0.555555555555556, 0.555555555555556, 0.555555555555556, 0.555555555555556, 
1.11111111111111, 1.11111111111111, 1.11111111111111, 1.11111111111111, 
1.11111111111111, 1.11111111111111, 1.11111111111111, 1.66666666666667, 
1.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 
1.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 2.22222222222222, 2.22222222222222, 
2.22222222222222, 2.22222222222222, 2.22222222222222, 2.22222222222222, 
2.22222222222222, 2.77777777777778, 2.77777777777778, 2.77777777777778, 
2.77777777777778, 2.77777777777778, 2.77777777777778, 2.77777777777778, 
3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3.88888888888889, 
3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 
3.88888888888889, 3.88888888888889, 4.44444444444444, 4.44444444444444, 
4.44444444444444, 4.44444444444444, 4.44444444444444, 4.44444444444444, 
4.44444444444444, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5.55555555555556, 5.55555555555556, 
5.55555555555556, 5.55555555555556, 5.55555555555556, 5.55555555555556, 
5.55555555555556, 6.11111111111111, 6.11111111111111, 6.11111111111111, 
6.11111111111111, 6.11111111111111, 6.11111111111111, 6.11111111111111, 
6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 
6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 7.22222222222222, 
7.22222222222222, 7.22222222222222, 7.22222222222222, 7.22222222222222, 
7.22222222222222, 7.22222222222222, 7.77777777777778, 7.77777777777778, 
7.77777777777778, 7.77777777777778, 7.77777777777778, 7.77777777777778, 
7.77777777777778, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 20, 20, 
20, 20.5555555555556, 20.5555555555556, 20.5555555555556, 20.5555555555556, 
20.5555555555556, 20.5555555555556, 20.5555555555556, 21.1111111111111, 
21.1111111111111, 21.1111111111111, 21.1111111111111, 21.1111111111111, 
21.1111111111111, 21.1111111111111, 21.6666666666667, 21.6666666666667, 
21.6666666666667, 21.6666666666667, 21.6666666666667, 21.6666666666667, 
21.6666666666667, 22.2222222222222, 22.2222222222222, 22.2222222222222, 
22.2222222222222, 22.2222222222222, 22.2222222222222, 22.2222222222222, 
22.7777777777778, 22.7777777777778, 22.7777777777778, 22.7777777777778, 
22.7777777777778, 22.7777777777778, 22.7777777777778, 23.3333333333333, 
23.3333333333333, 23.3333333333333, 23.3333333333333, 23.3333333333333, 
23.3333333333333, 23.3333333333333, 23.8888888888889, 23.8888888888889, 
23.8888888888889, 23.8888888888889, 23.8888888888889, 23.8888888888889, 
23.8888888888889, 24.4444444444444, 24.4444444444444, 24.4444444444444, 
24.4444444444444, 24.4444444444444, 24.4444444444444, 24.4444444444444, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25.5555555555556, 25.5555555555556, 
25.5555555555556, 25.5555555555556, 25.5555555555556, 25.5555555555556, 
25.5555555555556, 26.1111111111111, 26.1111111111111, 26.1111111111111, 
26.1111111111111, 26.1111111111111, 26.1111111111111, 26.1111111111111, 
26.6666666666667, 26.6666666666667, 26.6666666666667, 26.6666666666667, 
26.6666666666667, 26.6666666666667, 26.6666666666667, 27.2222222222222, 
27.2222222222222, 27.2222222222222, 27.2222222222222, 27.2222222222222, 
27.2222222222222, 27.2222222222222, 27.7777777777778, 27.7777777777778, 
27.7777777777778, 27.7777777777778, 27.7777777777778, 27.7777777777778, 
27.7777777777778), period = c(500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 166.666666666667, 166.666666666667, 
166.666666666667, 166.666666666667, 166.666666666667, 166.666666666667, 
166.666666666667, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 83.3333333333333, 83.3333333333333, 
83.3333333333333, 83.3333333333333, 83.3333333333333, 83.3333333333333, 
83.3333333333333, 71.4285714285714, 71.4285714285714, 71.4285714285714, 
71.4285714285714, 71.4285714285714, 71.4285714285714, 71.4285714285714, 
62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 55.5555555555555, 55.5555555555555, 
55.5555555555555, 55.5555555555555, 55.5555555555555, 55.5555555555555, 
55.5555555555555, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 45.4545454545455, 
45.4545454545455, 45.4545454545455, 45.4545454545455, 45.4545454545455, 
45.4545454545455, 45.4545454545455, 41.6666666666667, 41.6666666666667, 
41.6666666666667, 41.6666666666667, 41.6666666666667, 41.6666666666667, 
41.6666666666667, 38.4615384615385, 38.4615384615385, 38.4615384615385, 
38.4615384615385, 38.4615384615385, 38.4615384615385, 38.4615384615385, 
35.7142857142857, 35.7142857142857, 35.7142857142857, 35.7142857142857, 
35.7142857142857, 35.7142857142857, 35.7142857142857, 33.3333333333333, 
33.3333333333333, 13.8888888888889, 13.8888888888889, 13.8888888888889, 
13.5135135135135, 13.5135135135135, 13.5135135135135, 13.5135135135135, 
13.5135135135135, 13.5135135135135, 13.5135135135135, 13.1578947368421, 
13.1578947368421, 13.1578947368421, 13.1578947368421, 13.1578947368421, 
13.1578947368421, 13.1578947368421, 12.8205128205128, 12.8205128205128, 
12.8205128205128, 12.8205128205128, 12.8205128205128, 12.8205128205128, 
12.8205128205128, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.1951219512195, 
12.1951219512195, 12.1951219512195, 12.1951219512195, 12.1951219512195, 
12.1951219512195, 12.1951219512195, 11.9047619047619, 11.9047619047619, 
11.9047619047619, 11.9047619047619, 11.9047619047619, 11.9047619047619, 
11.9047619047619, 11.6279069767442, 11.6279069767442, 11.6279069767442, 
11.6279069767442, 11.6279069767442, 11.6279069767442, 11.6279069767442, 
11.3636363636364, 11.3636363636364, 11.3636363636364, 11.3636363636364, 
11.3636363636364, 11.3636363636364, 11.3636363636364, 11.1111111111111, 
11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 
11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 10.8695652173913, 10.8695652173913, 
10.8695652173913, 10.8695652173913, 10.8695652173913, 10.8695652173913, 
10.8695652173913, 10.6382978723404, 10.6382978723404, 10.6382978723404, 
10.6382978723404, 10.6382978723404, 10.6382978723404, 10.6382978723404, 
10.4166666666667, 10.4166666666667, 10.4166666666667, 10.4166666666667, 
10.4166666666667, 10.4166666666667, 10.4166666666667, 10.2040816326531, 
10.2040816326531, 10.2040816326531, 10.2040816326531, 10.2040816326531, 
10.2040816326531, 10.2040816326531, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
), species = c("Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", 
"Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", "Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", 
"Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", "Coscinodiscus", 
"Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", "Chaetoceros", 
"Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus", "Rhizosolenia robusta", 
"Chaetoceros", "Complexo Guinardia dactiolosolen", "Complexo Rhizosolenia proboscia", 
"Coscinodiscus", "Guinardia striata", "Hemidiscus"), spectrum = c(19458.7601688054, 
6017.54670807875, 13875.798895155, 159677.693338565, 207621691.203773, 
3811.69914489559, 136847.001892711, 14136.4255054037, 8441.65460457696, 
17393.0496685474, 107116.8751723, 158729101.553218, 2899.61406378871, 
109367.088430288, 9305.87807895499, 11281.5424641351, 18948.4670111303, 
60778.6363304813, 110444279.289477, 2115.32504891347, 82832.8053335067, 
6763.38451479777, 13121.2658179849, 18038.6267765227, 33607.4069291795, 
75631502.7582584, 1728.22087051592, 59272.5054559436, 6245.44059256122, 
13042.9317151286, 16194.4712529523, 18396.0869589645, 50308298.062295, 
1682.59037360351, 36077.8485929601, 6664.13511764911, 11586.486922396, 
14461.3639703533, 8618.02341292554, 30104857.8183676, 1829.55470236216, 
17444.1303666995, 6943.30907874546, 10065.8055812394, 12890.3342129596, 
3320.87177567782, 15728226.1750519, 1997.19168305309, 7496.86737007204, 
6494.49699262939, 8991.0442206116, 11273.6894319914, 1409.95460606118, 
7474051.51038637, 2055.47181627523, 3904.59296499914, 5411.21374815554, 
8009.43677697422, 9683.94295013324, 905.039269264689, 3534969.07308381, 
1969.74548519321, 2645.51718725985, 4213.53795956001, 6835.45158354146, 
8278.78258243896, 809.368222992939, 2019242.74949445, 1773.49233642477, 
2059.75611657007, 3447.71406634804, 5514.59631583194, 7086.85296659687, 
1029.00452520719, 1748319.38289315, 1534.69975564511, 1742.58835496923, 
3298.89669166208, 4231.48378350386, 6140.87287688144, 1589.99915823864, 
2302513.10644475, 1326.22111477987, 1460.83520829073, 3453.91772758991, 
3158.61443762274, 5403.37676725542, 2240.58170330882, 3758051.98565151, 
1189.17261885366, 1309.15805660222, 3504.63655589661, 2329.69936849746, 
4638.76554233306, 2587.82683410599, 6051426.94566691, 1125.88097909571, 
1506.42753971472, 3366.15728607311, 1692.67745433697, 6329281.44510128, 
465.097127046975, 2332.26971428103, 1148.91429609005, 1010.16428069083, 
1144.84760062549, 835.868490459267, 11786388.5541659, 580.540902458, 
4227.58085316718, 2069.70395083785, 1169.22909717042, 1528.89701387316, 
1177.81644915265, 17939351.822906, 768.324134796673, 8384.20576538291, 
3363.84036374411, 1328.77444763696, 1929.79301008027, 1603.80944005807, 
22072551.8733814, 939.826334041237, 13509.5531888272, 4302.05768271601, 
1333.90350144186, 2156.0968317067, 1782.90206768143, 22872261.5594672, 
1014.72869785231, 16247.7050605495, 4312.08542109906, 1201.00422830325, 
2016.3545817191, 1475.80311455503, 20605683.0392986, 987.729636677563, 
14326.6597963028, 3502.82884380579, 1068.22635801264, 1584.23902130377, 
885.52098211917, 16154018.9493131, 884.051415624282, 9403.97952840475, 
2432.21957973094, 1028.44586255351, 1112.2741035284, 425.350674116441, 
10888238.7624687, 737.604849745358, 5015.21428958028, 1617.83384179819, 
1092.19500833427, 775.417959531656, 262.796338903405, 6523946.78994595, 
619.444152461479, 2774.06615995364, 1229.32301921223, 1179.37390691533, 
611.832123456465, 270.500063450411, 3935359.27292958, 577.576157910486, 
1970.68839372538, 1097.61778471231, 1169.79680158148, 585.861605900478, 
306.461937341907, 2636434.34133975, 570.791954699915, 1546.33435152781, 
1017.04207010564, 1038.0403368466, 615.924290592657, 384.364356095856, 
1844089.45693978, 543.408580746617, 1160.181496196, 948.708595803658, 
857.592200250135, 610.549574570753, 573.52359517127, 1330983.85449444, 
501.889526739985, 892.119746535025, 920.320333398857, 693.36507826827, 
542.752570779926, 823.329956595525, 1143325.45509701, 465.154910154485, 
791.361592662822, 912.835866807245, 575.95823079491, 454.877305733286, 
992.242337199621, 1157490.54714983, 423.839059200258, 826.196612794713
)), row.names = c(NA, -201L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

And I have the following code to plot:
ggplot(df_spectral) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = spectrum, col = species), size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = spectrum), col = "black", size = .03) +
  facet_wrap(~species, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous("x", n.breaks = 10) +
  labs(x = "µHz") +
  theme_test()

However, I trying to add a secondary x-axis (column period) in a reverse way, below the main x-axis (column x), that is a frequency in µHz.
I don't to do this.
How could I perform this?

If you remove the "x" from scale_x_continuous then labs(x = "µHz") will be effective and the x axis label will be "µHz".

I don't see how you can have a secondary x-axis for period when the main axis is for x and there is no way to transform the values of x into those for period or vice versa. Unless I'm missing something, the two variables are completely unrelated.

Are you sure you don't want the secondary x axis on top? That is easily done.

@MichielDuvekot, yes, could be unnecessary add a second axis that are correlated. But I have another variables that I don't added here in example, that would be useful. So I would to just to do a way to added these another variable.

@RuiBarradas if you now how can I could add these variable on top it can help.
Thanks

Since the x* frequency constant seems to be 277.77, you can try something like :
  scale_x_continuous( n.breaks = 10,                      sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 277.777/.,                                          breaks = (277.777/c(0.5,5,10,15,20,25)) %>% round(),                                            name = "frequency")) for second axis on the top (default)

To add a secondary axis you need to first determine the two axis scales' ratios so that the 2nd is displayed in an equal axis length. In the code below that ratio is variable fac. Then, sec_axis will use that ratio to have the 2nd axis proportional to its values with ./fac. Function rev reverses the numbers.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

(fac <- with(df_spectral, range(x)/range(period)) |> max())
#> [1] 0.05555556

df_spectral %>%
  mutate(species = gsub(" ", "\n", species)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = spectrum)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = species), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_point(color = "black", size = .03) +
  facet_wrap(~species, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    n.breaks = 10,
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ rev(./fac), name = "period")
  ) +
  labs(x = "µHz") +
  theme_test()


Created on 2024-07-04 with reprex v2.1.0

Edit
After @VinceGreg's comments 1 and 2, I think he is probably right, period is the inverse of frequency. But I am not getting his 277.77 factor, fac2 below is computed from the data and is 2.777.
(fac2 <- with(df_spectral, x/period) |> max())
#> [1] 2.777778

df_spectral %>%
  mutate(species = gsub(" ", "\n", species)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = spectrum)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = species), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_point(color = "black", size = .03) +
  facet_wrap(~species, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    n.breaks = 10,
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ rev(fac2*.), name = "period")
  ) +
  labs(x = "µHz") +
  theme_test()


Created on 2024-07-04 with reprex v2.1.0

The secondary axis is not right. It is not "reverse" as the OP stated, its a 1/x form. Take a look to my recent comment on the original post.  A x value of 5.55 match a period of 50.

Nice (+1). For consistency, I recommend OP labels their axes either both by units (Hz and s) or both by quantity (frequency and period).

There were confusion in y comment on the original post. The x (frequency)  and the period  are linked togther, by frequency * period = constant = 277.77. I tried some values on the df to verify it.
I cant find a nice relation  other than 1/( frequency/1000000* period) = 3600

Thanks for the edit, but it still not right. The second axis should not be linear.  A x of 7.22 match a period of 38.46 (in the dataframe), the graph does not say that. I will post an answer shortly.

In this specific case, the relation between frequency (x) and the period is reciprocal (not "reverse"). The question might need clarifications. In the given dataframe,  x* period equal to 277.77 ( ex. 0.556*500 ; 6.1111 * 45.45). The second x-axis can't be linear. My solution imply specifying the
specifing the relation (~ 277.777/.), and get period breaks by evaluating 277.77/ some_selected_frequency_values .
(I used guides( x.sec = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))  to avoid the overlapping of the values on the second axis)
ggplot(df_spectral,aes(x = x, y = spectrum)) +
  geom_line( aes(col = species), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_point( col = "black", size = .03) +
  facet_wrap(~species, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_x_continuous( n.breaks = 10,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 277.777/.,
                                         breaks = (277.777/c(0.5,5,10,15,20,25)) %>% round(),
                                           name = "period")) +
  labs(x = "µHz")+
  guides( x.sec = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))


Created on 2024-07-04 with reprex v2.1.0
